# How to increase vertical separation of table of contents entries when using titletoc?

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I have a document like this:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}
    [0pt]
    {}
    {\makebox[10em][r]{\thecontentslabel}\hspace{1em}\bfseries}
    {\makebox[10em][r]{\thecontentslabel}\hspace{1em}\bfseries}
    {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\thecontentspage}
    []

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter{}
\chapter{Alpha}
\chapter{Beta}
\chapter{Gamma}

\end{document}
```

It generates a table of contents like this:

[image]

How do I increase the vertical spacing between these TOC entries?

Comment: You can use the currently empty, first mandatory argument of the `\titlecontents{chapter}` command to adjust teh spacing in the table of contents. You could use commands like `\medskip`, `\bigskip`,... or `\addvspace{<length>}` with a length of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that better?

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}
    [0pt]
    {}
    {\makebox[10em][r]{\thecontentslabel}\hspace{1em}\bfseries}
    {\makebox[10em][r]{\thecontentslabel}\hspace{1em}\bfseries}
    {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\thecontentspage}
    [\medskip]

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter{}
\chapter{Alpha}
\chapter{Beta}
\chapter{Gamma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh duh ... didn't realize I could use the last argument to `titlecontents` for this. Appreciate you pointing this out.

Comment: You're welcome. We're here to help!